# PlotRange with InputField in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Trying to understand work of InputField in Manipulate. My example code is:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[(ToExpression@list), 
PlotRange -> {{Automatic, max}, Automatic}], 
Control[{{list, "Range[10]", "List"}, 
InputField[#, String] &}], {{max, 10, "Max range"}, InputField}]
```

So, I have some list (here just `Range[10]` for simplicity), which can be entered by user in corresponding `InputField` and I want to control plotting range (`max` variable here). Now if I change `Range[...]` the plot range doesn't change, I suppose `max` should somehow become equal to `Max@ToExpression@list`. How to organize this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, the OP would like the user to be able to control the upper limit of the horizontal axis; and would like `max` to be set to the maximum range whenever `list` is changed, after which the user can change `max` as desired.  In that case, a typical approach is to use `TrackingFunction` to set the other variables.  I thought it would be more efficient to have another hidden variable  (no control) to be the actual list, since its value is needed in a couple of places.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> {{Automatic, max}, Automatic}],
 Control[{{str, "Range[10]", "List"},
   InputField[#, String] &,
   TrackingFunction -> (
     (str = #;
       list = ToExpression[str];
       (* Optional: add check here, set flag if not a List *)
       max = Length[list]) &)}],
 {{max, 10, "Max range"}, InputField},
 {{list, Range[10]}, ControlType -> None}
 ]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need, many thanks Michael!

Comment: @Sam_1q You're welcome!